# Symfony - form localization

Tags: symfony1, localization, internationalization, translation, symfony-1.4

I've started localizing my Symfony project but when I tried to use the `__()` function inside *actions.class.php* it came up with an error: `Call to undefined function __()`. The texts I have inside actions class are the form's labels and errors.

How can I localize these labels and errors if I am not allowed to use `__()` function? Is the simple translation into the catalogue enough? The same question applies for the Form classes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in form `$this->widgetSchema->setLabel('foobar');` will be automaticly translated: http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/08-Internationalisation-and-Localisation

the __() function usually works only in the templates with enabled i18n helper.
if you want to translate something in the action you will have to load the helper there. `sfLoader::loadHelpers(array('I18n'));`